# Why is $n^2 - 2$ never a multiple of $3$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, proof-writing

I know that for any $n$, $n^2 - 2$ is never a multiple of $3$. I feel like this is a rather simple proof, but I cannot figure out how to manipulate the definition of a multiple of $3$: $n$ is a multiple of $3$ if it can be written $n = 3k$ for some integer $k$.

Answer (score 5):

Note that modulo three, the squares are $1$ and $0$ only. That is, show that independently of $n$ being written as $3k,3k-1,3k+1$ then $n^2$ is of the form $3m$ or $3m+1$. If you want to be fancy, you may say that $2$ is a quadratic non-residue modulo $3$; that is, the equation $x^2=2\mod 3$ has no solutions.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

Any integer squared is either a multiple of $\;3\;$ or else of the form $\;3k+1\;$ ...

Answer (score 2):

$$(n^2-2)^2=\left[(n-1)n^2(n+1)+3-3n^2\right]+1$$

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $n$ is multiple of $3$ then $n=3k$ and $n^2-2=9k^2-2$ if this is divisible by $3$, then as $9k^2$ is divisible by $3$ this should imply $-2$ is divisible by $3$.(???)

Suppose $n$ is not a multiple of $3$ and $n=3k+1$ and $n^2-2=9k^2+6k-1$ if this is divisible by $3$, for similar reasons this would  imply $-1$ is divisible by $3$.(???)

Suppose $n$ is not a multiple of $3$ and $n=3k+2$ and $n^2-2=9k^2+12k+2$ if this is divisible by $3$, for similar reasons this would  imply $2$ is divisible by $3$.(???)

Thus, $n^2-2$ is not divisible by $3$